# Derivation of Likelihood Function for Random Effects Parameters

Tags: probability, random-variables, bayesian, regression-analysis

I initially posted this question in CV, but getting no responses or interest, I am deleting it there, and trying my luck in math.stackexchange, hoping that the math details of the following derivation can find someone interested.

Background: Estimation of the multivariate parameters of random effects in regression models. In particular, I am trying to understand Douglas Bates' exposition of the estimation of the vector ***b*** of random effects for the `lmer` function of the `lme4` package - there is one step in the reasoning on *page* *5* of this [document](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB4QFjAAahUKEwjsiZ7Zqo7GAhWIe5IKHf9JACs&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcran.r-project.org%2Fweb%2Fpackages%2Flme4%2Fvignettes%2FTheory.pdf&ei=LAF9VezDF4j3yQT_k4HYAg&usg=AFQjCNGTWY0M6Umxgf2kEsVhKDil1ZMnIg&sig2=ksb3Op9SACtzOrI0FOj3Bw) that I don't get.

Since we can't observe the actualized values of the *random effect vector* ($B$) in a regression model with fixed and random effects, we resort to maximum likelihood (or Bayesian (?)) strategies: We do observe the *response vector* ($Y$), so we focus on the distribution of $B\mid Y=y_\text{observed}$, or its proxy $U\mid Y=y_\text{observed}$, with $B$ being a linear transformation of $U$. So far so good.

He establishes that a pdf,   $h(u\mid y, \theta, \beta, \sigma) = f(y\mid u,\theta,\beta,\sigma)\, f(u,\sigma)$ is going to be proportional to the distribution we were after, I suppose $f(u\mid y, \theta, \beta, \sigma)$. This is not explicitly stated, but if the assumption is correct, I guess $U\mid Y$ would really equal,  $f(u\mid y, \theta, \beta, \sigma) = \frac{f(y\mid u,\theta,\beta,\sigma)\, f(u,\sigma)}{f(y,\sigma)}$  (?).

And now to the point of the question... The next line states that normalizing $h$ would entail dividing it by $\int_{\mathbb {R}^q}h(u\mid y, \theta, \beta, \sigma)\,du$, $q$ being the number of random effects. This last equation is a likelihood ($\sim$) function $L(\theta,\beta,\sigma\mid y)$. I don't understand this very last step, and I wonder if it constitutes a valid question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's basically Bayes Rule. Recall the Bayes Rule formula:

$P(A|B)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(B)}=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{\int P(B|A)P(A)dA}$

Basically, we can think of $h$ as $P(B|A)P(A)$ But, what we're really interested in is $P(A|B)$ (the probability of being type A conditional on information B) and in order to get in we need to divide by $\int P(B|A)P(A)dA$

Edit: I scrapped my original preamble since I found it confusing.